# Is there a tool to refactor a YAML file, order the lines, switch from dot format to indent?

Tags: symfony, yaml

In Symfony 2, I am using the translation:update command to generate translations YML files from my templates where I already have defined teh translation strings.

I get .yml files where everything is mixed up.

I am searching for a tool, a script that could refactor this :

```
menu.home: __en.menu.home
menu.projects: __en.menu.projects
information.address: __en.information.address
information.agent.languages.english: __en.information.agent.languages.english
information.agent.languages.russian: __en.information.agent.languages.russian
information.agent.name: __en.information.agent.name
```

to :

```
information:
  address: __en.information.address
  agent:
    languages:
      english: __en.information.agent.languages.english
      russian: __en.information.agent.languages.russian
    name: __en.information.agent.name
menu:
  home: __en.menu.home
  projects: __en.menu.projects
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a code snippet to do what you ask:

```
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Yaml;
use Symfony\Component\Yaml\Dumper;
// ...

$dottedYaml = Yaml::parse(file_get_contents('dotted-file.yml'));

$nestedYaml = array();
foreach ($dottedYaml as $dottedKey => $value) {
    $levels = explode('.', $dottedKey);
    $levelYaml =& $nestedYaml;
    do {
        $level = array_shift($levels);
        if (!isset($levelYaml[$level])) {
            $levelYaml[$level] = array();
        }
        $levelYaml =& $levelYaml[$level];
    } while (count($levels));
    $levelYaml = $value;
}

$dumper = new Dumper();
file_put_contents('nested-file.yml', $dumper->dump($nestedYaml, 5));
```

Please be aware that even though my code works for your example if you have something like this:

```
menu: "here is the problem"
menu.home: __en.menu.home
menu.projects: __en.menu.projects
```

You cannot actually convert to a nested notation unless you decide some kind of convention if a certain level contains a scalar value AND an array of nested values:

```
menu:
  home: __en.menu.home
  projects: __en.menu.projects
  value: "here is the problem" # we made up a "value" attribute to store the top level value
```